# Wrapping Pyro4 name server

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pyro

I made a class to allow me to start and stop a pyro name server from a script (i.e. not having to start multiple programs such as in the [tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/tutorials.html)). The class is as follow:

```
class NameServer(Pyro4.threadutil.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, isDeamon, port=0, enableBroadcast=True, 
                 bchost=None, bcport=None, unixsocket=None, nathost=None, natport=None):
        super(NameServer,self).__init__()
        self.setDaemon(isDeamon)
        self.host=host
        self.started=Pyro4.threadutil.Event()
        self.unixsocket = unixsocket

        self.port = port
        self.enableBroadcast = enableBroadcast 
        self.bchost = bchost
        self.bcport = bcport
        self.nathost = nathost
        self.natport = natport       


        #This code is taken from Pyro4.naming.startNSloop
        self.ns_daemon = Pyro4.naming.NameServerDaemon(self.host, self.port, self.unixsocket, 
                                                 nathost=self.nathost, natport=self.natport)
        self.uri    = self.ns_daemon.uriFor(self.ns_daemon.nameserver)
        internalUri = self.ns_daemon.uriFor(self.ns_daemon.nameserver, nat=False)
        self.bcserver=None
        self.ns = self.ns_daemon.nameserver        

        if self.unixsocket:
            hostip = "Unix domain socket"
        else:
            hostip = self.ns_daemon.sock.getsockname()[0]
            if hostip.startswith("127."):
                enableBroadcast=False
            if enableBroadcast:
                # Make sure to pass the internal uri to the broadcast responder.
                # It is almost always useless to let it return the external uri,
                # because external systems won't be able to talk to this thing anyway.
                bcserver=Pyro4.naming.BroadcastServer(internalUri, self.bchost, self.bcport)
                bcserver.runInThread()


    def run(self):
        try:
            self.ns_daemon.requestLoop()
        finally:
            self.ns_daemon.close()
            if self.bcserver is not None:
                self.bcserver.close()


    def startNS(self):
        self.start()

    def stopNS(self):
        self.ns_daemon.shutdown()
        if self.bcserver is not None:
            self.bcserver.shutdown()
```

Now, if I run the following script

```
import socket
import Pyro4
from threading import Thread
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
from datetime import datetime

HMAC_KEY = "1234567890"

Pyro4.config.HMAC_KEY = HMAC_KEY         
sys.excepthook = Pyro4.util.excepthook 


[... definition of class NameServer given previously ...]



class Dummy:
    x = {}    


    def getX(self):
        return self.x


class Worker(Process):

    def run(self): 

        Pyro4.config.HMAC_KEY = HMAC_KEY         
        sys.excepthook = Pyro4.util.excepthook    

        for i in range(10):
            a = datetime.now() 
            with Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:dummy") as obj:   
                obj.getX()  
            print i, (datetime.now() - a).total_seconds()



def main():


    nameserver = NameServer(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), False)
    nameserver.startNS()

    daemon=Pyro4.Daemon(socket.gethostname(), port=7676)                 # make a Pyro daemon

    obj = Dummy()

    uri=daemon.register(obj)   # register the greeting object as a Pyro object
    nameserver.ns.register("dummy", uri)  # register the object with a name in the name server

    thread = Thread(target = daemon.requestLoop)
    thread.setDaemon(1)
    thread.start()
    time.sleep(1)

    worker = Worker()

    worker.start()  



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following output:

```
0 1.078
1 1.05
2 1.013
3 1.037
4 1.013
5 1.087
6 1.063
7 1.1
8 1.063
9 1.05
```

However, if I run this code as two different programs without using my NameServer class, I dont get these delays. For example, runing the first script:

```
import Pyro4
import sys

HMAC_KEY = "1234567890"

Pyro4.config.HMAC_KEY = HMAC_KEY         
sys.excepthook = Pyro4.util.excepthook 


class Dummy:
    x = {}    

    def getX(self):
        return self.x


def main():

    obj = Dummy()
    Pyro4.Daemon.serveSimple({obj: "dummy"}, ns = False)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the second script

```
import Pyro4
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
from datetime import datetime

HMAC_KEY = "1234567890"

Pyro4.config.HMAC_KEY = HMAC_KEY         
sys.excepthook = Pyro4.util.excepthook 



class Worker(Process):

    def run(self): 

        Pyro4.config.HMAC_KEY = HMAC_KEY         
        sys.excepthook = Pyro4.util.excepthook    

        for i in range(10):
            a = datetime.now() 
            with Pyro4.Proxy("[the URI given by Pyro when running script 1]") as obj:   
                obj.getX()  
            print i, (datetime.now() - a).total_seconds()


def main():

    worker = Worker()
    worker.start()  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following results

```
0 0.053
1 0.049
2 0.051
3 0.05
4 0.013
5 0.049
6 0.051
7 0.05
8 0.013
9 0.049
```

... what can be wrong with the first approach? I don't understand why I get delays of 1 second at each Pyro call. Profiling it tells me that it is the socket method connect that takes 1 second...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what exactly is wrong, but you can try my new [PyroMP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyroMP) package which has a wrapper for a the Pyro4 NameServer as well as an easy way to create processes.
Your example will look like:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
from datetime import datetime

import Pyro4
import PyroMP
import PyroMP.log_server as log


class Dummy(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = {}

    def getX(self):
        return self.x


class Worker(PyroMP.Service):

    def run(self):
        logger = self.get_logger()
        for i in range(10):
            a = datetime.now()
            with Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:dummy") as obj:
                obj.getX()
            logger.info("{}: {}".format(i, (datetime.now() - a).total_seconds()))


def main():
    with PyroMP.NameServer(), log.LogServer():
        log.set_loglevel("INFO")

        daemon = Pyro4.Daemon()# make a Pyro daemon

        obj = Dummy()

        uri = daemon.register(obj)   # register the greeting object as a Pyro object
        ns = PyroMP.NameServer.locate()
        ns.register("dummy", uri)  # register the object with a name in the name server

        thread = Thread(target=daemon.requestLoop)
        thread.setDaemon(1)
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)

        with Worker() as worker:
            worker.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output is:

```
2014-02-19 18:56:32,877 - LogServer.WORKER               - INFO     - 0: 0.0
2014-02-19 18:56:32,892 - LogServer.WORKER               - INFO     - 1: 0.016
2014-02-19 18:56:32,892 - LogServer.WORKER               - INFO     - 2: 0.0
2014-02-19 18:56:32,894 - LogServer.WORKER               - INFO     - 3: 0.001
2014-02-19 18:56:32,940 - LogServer.WORKER               - INFO     - 4: 0.031
2014-02-19 18:56:32,956 - LogServer.WORKER               - INFO     - 5: 0.015
2014-02-19 18:56:32,956 - LogServer.WORKER               - INFO     - 6: 0.0
```